# Setting default scale for iOS Simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, ios-simulator

Is there a way to set the default scale with which iOS Simulator should open, for example, 75%?

The native resolution of the New iPad is too large for my display, so I have to press ⌘+2 or ⌘+3 every single time I want to test an app while being able to see the entire screen.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen questions on this before, and the answer is no. I would love it if the answer was yes, but it is not. I hope that Apple adds this feature in a future release.